# Color codes and string interpolation

Tags: ruby, console-application

I am trying to colorize text. Say I want blue text. This is the way I get it:

```
"\e[34mThis is blue text.\e[0m"
```

I am using `define_method` to create multiple methods (one for each color). I keep the color code for each color in an array. I iterate over both the color array and the color code, and do this:

```
"\e#{code}m[#{self}\e[0m"
```

When I run it, I get `"m[test"` instead of the colorized text.

Any thoughts? If, instead of `#{code}`, I put the actual code, it works, but that'd be like 20 `if`s, one for each color, and it won't be DRY.

Comment: Your issue has nothing to do with rubygems.

Comment: I am creating one so I thought I'd add the tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are likely a victim of copy-paste :)

```
#               ⇓  incorrect
puts "\e#{code}m[#{self}\e[0m"

#       ⇓  correct
puts "\e[#{code}m#{self}\e[0m"
```

The opening square bracket should follow `\e`, not `m`.